# Origin of Büchi arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic, math-history

What is the origin of [Büchi arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_arithmetic)? Wikipedia only says it is named in his honour.

"A Survival Guide to Presburger arithmetic" mentions in section 6.1 what was the motivation for the arithmetic.

*Edit*

From [this paper](https://On%20the%20Existential%20Theories%20of%20Buchi%20Arithmetic%20%C2%A8%20and%20Linear%20p-adic%20Fields):

A basic result about Büchi arithmetic is that a subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}^n$ is first-order definable over $\langle \mathbb{N}, +, V_p \rangle$ if and only if $X$ is p-automatic, that is, recognisable by an automaton under a base-p encoding of natural numbers. This result was first stated by Buchi in [they [cite this paper]](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/3930).

Now the question is within this paper where is the result stated.

Comment: See [Julius Richard Büchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Richard_B%C3%BCchi): student of Paul Bernays and thus studied in the context of Hilbert school. Like [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) it must be "located" in the context of subsystem of Peano arithmetic expressive enough still retaining decidability.

Comment: See [On the Expressiveness of Buchi Arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.12892): "the expressive power of Buchi arithmetic, an extension of Presburger arithmetic, the first-order theory of the structure $\langle \mathbb N; 0; 1;+ \rangle$. Buchi
arithmetic additionally allows for expressing restricted divisibility properties while retaining decidability."

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA! Just to make it a bit precise my question has also a historical side. I am interested in who and when introduced first this arithmetic in the literature.

Comment: Original paper: Buchi, [Weak second-order arithmetic and finite automata. Math. Logic Quart. 1960)](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/3930)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I actually printed out this paper. But your link has better typeset than mine. However, where in the paper does he introduce the arithmetic? Did you see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Büchi's "Weak Second-Order Arithmetic and Finite Automata", Section 5, Theorem 4, Büchi states that the natural numbers with + and a predicate recognizing powers of 2 ($Pw_2$) is expressively equivalent to the Weak Monadic Second-Order Theory of 1 Successor.

However, the proof there is fundamentally wrong. Büchi claims that:
$$E(x,y): Pw_2(x) \wedge \exists u, v: [(y=u+x+v) \wedge (u < v) \wedge [v = 0 \vee 2x \leq v]]$$
is an expression of "$x$ occurs in the representation of $y$ as a sum of powers of 2". But the requirement on $v$ (meant to represent the digits to the left of $x$) actually needs to be that it is divisible by $2x$.

Thanks to MauroALLEGRANZA's comment I was able to find
"Logic and $p$-Recognizable Sets of Integers" (Bruyère, V., Hansel, G., Michaux, C., Villemaire, R., 1994 https://doi.org/doi:10.36045/bbms/1103408547) which elaborates on the history from there in section 4.4:

R. MacNaughton pointed out this mistake in his 1963 review of Büchi's paper (Journal of Symbolic Logic 28.01) and proposed an easy fix of replacing "is a power of 2" by $E(x,y)$ above.

Someone named M. Boffa suggested to V. Bruyère in a personal communication in 1985 to replace $E(x,y)$ with the $V_p$ predicates now in use, which he published in something called "Entiers et automates finis, Mémoire de fin d’études, Université de Mons (1985)". I don't know French and can't find the paper so any help with this bit would be appreciated.

C. Michaux and F. Point also prove the equivalence using $V_p$ in "Les ensembles $k$-reconnaissables sont définissables dans <$\mathbb{N},+,V_k$> C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris 303 (1986)." Which I also can't find.

Are these two papers aware of each other? V. Bruyère and C. Michaux collaborated in the 1994 paper.

Comment: For the thesis, one could contact V. Bruyère. For the other paper i belive that the journal is "Comptes Rendus de l'Académie de Sciences de Paris" and they seem to have digitalised versions. https://www.academie-sciences.fr/fr/Communiques-de-presse/les-comptes-rendus-en-libre-acces.html